# Parsing JSON: brackets in response

Tags: iphone, json, sbjson, json-framework

I want to parse this JSON [YouTube recently featured](http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/standardfeeds/recently_featured?v=2&alt=json).
This is how I get the title of the videos:

```
NSString *response = [request responseString];
    responseDict = [response JSONValue];

videoTitleArray = [responseDict valueForKeyPath:@"feed.entry.title.$t"];
```

And it works like I want it.
But I also want to display the author of the video.
But the following code for this does not work properly:

```
videoAuthorArray = [responseDict valueForKeyPath:@"feed.entry.author.name.$t"];
    NSLog(@"%@", videoAuthorArray);
```

The list of the authors I get looks like this:

```
(
    author 1
),
    (
    author 2
),
    (
    author 3
),
    (
    author 4
),
```

I can't display the names in for example a table view because of the brackets.
How can I display the author names like the video titles?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you see an Author you see this:

```
"author":[{"name":{"$t":"mls"},"uri":{"$t":"http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/mls"},"yt$userId":{"$t":"SZbXT5TLLW_i-5W8FZpFsg"}}]
```

this means: author is an array of author objects

each author object has: `name` object, a `uri` object and a `yt$userId` object

each of this objects described above is a `NSDictionary`

formated we have:

```
"author":[
  {
    "name": {
      "$t":"mls"
    },
    "uri": {
      "$t":"http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/mls"
    },
    "yt$userId":{
      "$t":"SZbXT5TLLW_i-5W8FZpFsg"
    }
  }
],
```

so if you have your `videoAuthorArray` each element is an `NSDictionary` and has this keys: `name`, `uri` and `yt$userId`

each of this objects has an `NSDictionary` with a single key: `$t` witch has the value